# CodeIgniter - When using $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1' how to use other controllers?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, controllers

When using

`$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`

and I want to use other controllers in my routing for example:

```
$route['del/(:any)'] = 'crud/del';
```

it won't work. I guess it will use

`pages/view/del/$1`

and not my crud-controller when deleting an item. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can I use $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = '(:any)/(:any)/index';

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated, `$route['(:any)']` will match *any* URL, so place your other custom routes *before* the "catch-all" route:

```
$route['del/(:any)'] = 'crud/del';
// Other routes as needed...
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Answer (score 2):

Its hundred percent working

```
$route['(:any)'] url is placed last in your routes file

$route['(:any)/company_product_deal_detail']    =   "mypage_product_picture/deal_detail/$1";
$route['(:any)/company_service_deals/(:any)']    =   "mypage_service_deal_list/index/$1";
$route['(:any)/company_service_deals']    =   "mypage_service_deal_list/index/$1";

$route['(:any)']    =   "company/index/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old question, but I have found myself a nice solution.

By default, CodeIgniter gives priority to URL's from routes config (even if straight controller, method etc. specified), so I have reversed this priority this way:

In `system/core/Router.php` find `_parse_routes` method.

Add this code under literal route match:

```
$cont_segments = $this->_validate_request($this->uri->segments);
if ($cont_segments == $this->uri->segments) {
  return $this->_set_request($cont_segments);
}
```

I agree, that this approach is kinda wrong, because we edit file from system/core, but I needed a fast soluttion to work with a lot of URL's.