# Overriding routes in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter - When using $route[‘(:any)’] = ‘pages/view/$1’ how to use other controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023189/codeigniter-when-using-routeany-pages-view-1-how-to-use-other-con)

I'm working on a url shortener/redirect web app in codeigniter and have ran into an issue with my routes.

The first route i have is:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "redirect/index/$1";
```

This is what handles the redirect, so example.com/dwB would goto the redirect controller.

Underneath I have a few routes that override that for pages and other controllers etc. They work fine when i describe the entire url including arguments etc but I have now ran into trouble as i have some dynamic urls like:

```
 example.com/stats/view/dwB
```

Or facebook auth responses etc, which i can't obviously write a route for. I've tried using something like:

```
 $route['stats/view/(:any)'] = "stats/view/$1";
```

but none of these appear to override the first route. Here is my entire routes.php document.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "redirect/index/$1";

$route['shorten/create'] = "shorten/create"; // overwrite the previous route

$route['stats/view/(:any)'] = "stats/view/$1"; // allow the stats controller to be used

$route['login'] = "auth/login"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used
$route['register'] = "auth/register"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used
$route['auth_social/fblogin'] = "auth_social/fblogin"; // allow the login(auth) controller    to be used
$route['dashboard'] = "dashboard"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used
$route['auth/logout'] = "auth/logout"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used
$route['auth'] = "auth/index"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used

$route['default_controller'] = "pages";

$route['404_override'] = '404';
```

Comment: did you try putting `$route['(:any)'] = "redirect/index/$1";` at the end?

Comment: yeh putting it at the end has worked. Do you know why?

Comment: @Chris: The "any" route matches *any* URL, so it will always get triggered. Placing that route below the other custom routes will give the others a chance to be triggered first (if a match occurs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, place your "any" route at the end of your custom routes, like this:

```
$route['shorten/create'] = "shorten/create"; // overwrite the previous route

$route['stats/view/(:any)'] = "stats/view/$1"; // allow the stats controller to be used

$route['login'] = "auth/login"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used
$route['register'] = "auth/register"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used
$route['auth_social/fblogin'] = "auth_social/fblogin"; // allow the login(auth) controller    to be used
$route['dashboard'] = "dashboard"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used
$route['auth/logout'] = "auth/logout"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used
$route['auth'] = "auth/index"; // allow the login(auth) controller to be used

// Move "any" route down here...
$route['(:any)'] = "redirect/index/$1";
```