# configuring routes.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, uri

I'm just starting a new project alone and I'm stuck in Codeigniter's URI configuration.

I'm using xampp, and so far I have a folder with my site in it with this path:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/new_admin/site/application
c:/xampp/htdocs/new_admin/site/system
```

As it says in Codeigniter's manual, I added to the config.php the base URL which I consider is this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/new_admin/';
```

I left index_page in blank:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I want my URI to look like:

```
http://localhost/new_admin/[controller]/[method]
```

for example:

```
http://localhost/new_admin/admin/index
```

So in the file routes.php I did this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin';
$route['(:any)'] = 'admin/index';
```

But it's not even showing the result of the method index. The error is 404.

Since I can't find solution in documentation, I think I'm missing something.

How can I do to make this work as I want?

Update: I wrote this in .htaccess file

```
#Deny from all

RewriteEngine On   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: Are you using mod_rewrite?

Comment: @Kisaragi I don't know, how can I check this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11023778/552116

Comment: @Kisaragi I have checked in the .htaccess file, and no I'm not using mod_rewrite.

Comment: If "c:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/site/" is the path to your website files, the URL would be something like "http://localhost/mysite/site" ? where has "new_admin" come from?

Comment: yea you cant just come up with any name and place it in your config. Your file name needs to match what you put in there. So if your file name is `site` then your `base_url` shoudld be `'http://localhost/site/';`

Comment: @Craig well new_admin would be "mysite" so: http://localhost/new_admin. I updated the question whith this, please check

Comment: i see that you made the update. are you using mod_rewrite to get rid of index.php. If you are not, then so far this should work: `http://localhost/new_admin/index.php/admin/index` Let me know if that works

Comment: @CodeGodie I activated mod_rewrite as it says in here: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html but still not working with the url that I want

Comment: $config['base_url'] = '//localhost/new_admin/site/' see if that works.

Comment: did you enable `mod_rewrite` in Apache?

Comment: @CodeGodie I just touched .htaccess file that comes inside Codeigniter's Application folder

Comment: im not sure how to do this in Xampp since I use Wamp. But try the instructions on this link and let me know if it works: http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/ You basically have to uncomment a line in httpd.conf (or remove the `#` from that line)

Comment: Also, the `.htaccess` file you want to edit, is the one that is outside of the `application` folder. it should be a file next to the main `index.php` file within the same directory.

Comment: `http://localhost/new_admin/index.php/[controller]/[method] ` does this link work?

Comment: Have you tried pointing your base_url `to http://localhost/new_admin/site` to see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a day of trying I discovered that I was wrong when configuring my virtual host in

```
c:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

This is how it is now and working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/new_admin/site"
  ServerName local.new_admin
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/new_admin/site">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  # to allow access from my local network add this line so other PC on my   network are allowed in but not anything from the internet
 # If you want the world to be allowed in uncomment this line
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then on

```
c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

I added this lines:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    local.new_admin  #this is my site
```

And after fixing that I added a new .htaccess file in this directory:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/new_admin/site/
```

which contains:

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 0 
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime 0
```

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.

#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

#previously this would not have been possible.

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder

#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder

#Submitted by: Fabdrol

#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,

#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the

#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

```
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Next to Codeigniter's application folder and system folder, in order to add the mod_rewrite permissions

Now to access localy  to my project, I just type:

```
http://local.new_admin/admin/index
```

Hope this is usefull for newbies like me.