# how to write .htaccess file for my codeigniter Website

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, seo

Here is my URL with SEO Title

```
http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/assetsrecovered/index.php/pages/page?seo=ar-about-us
```

i want to change it in

```
http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/assetsrecovered/ar-about-us
```

**`index.php/pages/page?seo=`** this portion should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All i set `config.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

And

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

After that in `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";  // Default Controller
$route['pages/([a-zA-Z-0-9.&_]+)'] = "pages/index/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I called the dynamic menu with slug (or SEO title), in my `header.php`

```
<?php
foreach($menu as $menu_item){
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>pages/<?php echo $menu_item['seo'];?>">
<?php echo $menu_item['name'];?>
</a>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

My Controller is `pages.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($seo='')
    {
      $this->load->model('MPages');
      $data['seo']=$this->MPages->get_seo_by_page_slug($seo)->result();
      // Loading Common Views
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('topbar',$data);
        $this->load->view('mypage_view',$data);
    }
}
```

Finally i am getting these URLs

```
http://mysitelive/pages/ar-about-us
http://mysitelive/pages/ar-services
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `index.php` from url using `.htaccess` like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

To remove remaining part, use `routes.php`

```
$route['{default_controller}/{default_method}/(:num)'] = "{original_controller}/{original_method}/$1";
```

Comment: should i put $route['{default_controller}/{default_method}/(:num)'] = "{original_controller}/{original_method}/$1"; ????

Comment: `$route['(:any)'] = "pages/page/$1";`

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023189/codeigniter-when-using-routeany-pages-view-1-how-to-use-other-con)

Comment: currently mu routes.php is 
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)'] = "pages/page/$1";
but still url is same

Comment: If this not working try to change order in routes.php file. Like this `$route['(:any)'] = "pages/page/$1";$route['default_controller'] = "welcome"; $route['404_override'] = '';`

Comment: @Gvidas what does it mean ? and then in controller action function change your $_GET['seo'] to $seo.

Comment: In your function somewhere should be line where you take seo title from get method, so you have to change it

Comment: @anubhava can you please

Answer (score 0):

to remove index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

This .htaccess file will allow to write links without index.php in url, but it will still look like:
`http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/assetsrecovered/pages/page?seo=ar-about-us`

You need to modify your routes and controller to remove `?seo=`.

In controller your action should be `public function page($seo)` something like this and route should be `$route['pages/page/(:any)'] = "pages/page/$1";` and then in controller action function change your `$_GET['seo']` to `$seo`.

And after this you can access your page like:
`http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/assetsrecovered/pages/page/ar-about-us`

If you want to remove `/pages/page` then you can add this to your `routes.php`:
`$route['(:any)'] = "pages/page/$1`. But use this with precautions, because wrong placement in routes file can prevent other routes from working